# Importing Python package inside a large ZIP file

Tags: python, import, jar, zip, pythonpath

I am trying to embed a Python package inside a JAR file, so I can use this artifact for its execution in a JVM instance as well as through a Python interpreter (Python 3.5).

Even though the JAR file is generated correctly, I can't import the package from Python, raising a "No module named XXXX" error.

The facts are the following:

- Unzipping the JAR file works. I can import the package from the extracted directory.
- Even though my intention is to have a FAT JAR, I have also generated a version without dependencies, and the light version of my app can be used by Python interpreter without any problem.
- The FAT JAR size is about 170 Mb. Most of the JVM logic is stored inside a directory called *com*, so there are lots and lots of subdirectories inside it.

I have been searching for information about how ZIP importing from python works, but I have not found any answers at this point.

I would like to ask you about a hint about how ZIP module lookup works in Python, so I can prepare a well structured JAR file.